# How to geometrically simplify a door which contains creases?

Tags: edges, geometry

I downloaded a high-quality door from an online source and this is what it looks like:

[image: door_visual]

But when you examine in wireframe view, there's a lot of edges/creases:

[image: door_wireframe]

I tried changing the `Mean Crease` in the *Transform* option setting to zero but it deforms the door completely:

[image: door__changed_crease]

Are there any other methods of simplifying the geometries of this door (i.e. removing the creases or just having a single face on either side)?

[image]

Comment: if you deactivate its modifiers you won't have anymore problems with the creases, do you need them?

Comment: @moonboots - If it means that there are no changes visually and there will be less geometry data then no, I do not need them :)

Comment: it can cause problem if you need some close-up shots of the handle or of the hinges, because they will look sharp and not smooth, but other than that it won't change a lot. By the way, the topology is not very good, you could also completely re-do it.

Comment: @moonboots - Thanks, I'm still learning the ropes and the door was taken from an online source. It fits well with the building model I have but if the topology is not as good then I guess I could attempt to re-create it.

Comment: well it really depends on your goal, if it stays small in your whole scene and your render image you don't have to care a lot, if you need close-up shots, you'll need to think how to make a nice door.

Comment: @moonboots - Good to know, many thanks for your advice!

Comment: in the second case you'll probably need to use Subsurf to smooth the object, but it will simplify a lot if hinges, handle and wood plank are 3 separate mesh, as it would be in real life.